# How to limit the actor outputs in a specific range?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to apply deep-deterministic-policy-gradient (DDPG) on a process control problem. The action outputs are continuous. For example, the temperature of the process would be 25 to 100 degree C, or the motor spin rate would be 0 to 3.0 rpm. The purpose of my work is to improve the product quality of that process by applying the best action outputs to that process. I think Actor-Critic and DDPG algorithm will be a good approach to my problem.

When I was implementing the Actor part, I found most of the examples online limited the Actor outputs in the range of (-1, 1). This is, a tanh activation function.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def actor_network(state):
    net = tf.layers.dense(state, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    action = tf.layers.dense(net, action_dimension, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    return action
```

Here's my question:

How should I revise my actor network to limited the action outputs in the range of (25, 100) for temperature, and (0, 3.0) for motor spin rate?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rescale the action through a liner operation with known "weights"? If you for simplicity use logistic and not tanh as your activation, then return `tf.add(tf.constant(<lower-bound>), tf.scalar_mul(tf.constant(<upper> - <lower>), action))`
Haven't tested, but seems reasonable. If you want the tanh it is straightforward to fix the calculation accordingly.